# call function on button click in handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I have been tryinng to call a function on button click in handlebars view,
but unable to do so.

Now, I am new to it and maybe somehow missing the obvious. would love some help on this.

basically, it's a table which I am creating dynamically, but unable to call the function on button click.

here's the relevant code inside calendar.hbs

```
 {{#each events}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{this.subject}}</td>
        <td>{{this.start.dateTime}} ({{this.start.timeZone}})</td>
        <td>{{this.end.dateTime}} ({{this.end.timeZone}})</td>
        <td>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            {{#each this.attendees}}
              <li class="border p-1" title="{{this.emailAddress.address}}">
                {{this.emailAddress.name}}
              </li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>{{this.location.displayName}}</td>     
        <td><button onclick="editEvent({{this}})" >Edit</button></td>   
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
```

and I have put the function in layout.hbs
inside script tag like this

```
 <script>
  function editEvent(val){
    return function(e){
      console.log('val : ',val);
    }
  }
</script>
```

but I still get an error saying `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"`

please tell me where am I going wrong.

now, I also tried doing it in app.js like this

```
hbs.registerHelper("editEvent", function(event) {
  console.log('event : ',event);
  });
```

and then used in in calendar.hbs like
Edit

and it was working I could see it in the console. but the problem was that it seemed to be calling the function on load and it kind of was automatically calling the function for all rows of the table on load... which I dont want.

so, what is the best way to do it?

EDIT:
I looked at the html there and it shows up like this
okay, I looked at it and it's showing up as

```
<td><button onclick="editEvent([object Object])" >Edit</button></td>
```

not sure how to fix it though.

I am not sure why you marked it as duplicate.
The questions linked to - dont answer the question I have . But if you do feel that my question is answered here, then please at least send me a message with how to fix my problem.

Comment: Look at the HTML and JavaScript you are generating from Handlebars, not just the template itself. It's much easier to debug error messages when you look at the source code it is talking about.

Comment: looked at the html generated and have updated the original question to show how it looks. tell me if you get any ideas.

Comment: `editEvent([object Object])`, well, there definitely is an unexpected identifier there. You are missing a comma in your array. (Or rather, you are trying to treat your code as if you have one JavaScript program and not two different JavaScript programs which pass data between them using HTTP).

Comment: well, please let me know how to fix it. I have spent a hec lot of time on this and still unable to fix.

Comment: @Quentin I am not sure why you marked it as duplicate. I have already seen the questions you mentioned and it doesnt help. if you have got ideas of how it can help then please tell me.